# Can I call custom javascript from an R jupyter notebook

Tags: javascript, r, jupyter

I have a `Jupyter Notebook` which is using the R programming language. I would like to call `javascript functions` within this R notebook.

I know there is a way to do this, because there are javascript based libraries that you can call from R, but I cannot find any examples of wrapping a javascript function, so it can be used by R.

Even an example of assigning javascript to a `R variable` and then calling that R variable would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`js::js_eval()` can evaluate a string of JavaScript within R. From `?js::js_eval`:

> ```
> # Stateless evaluation
> js_eval("(function() {return 'foo'})()")
> ```

For more complicated JavaScript operations, check out `V8`, which lets you keep a JavaScript instance for more than one line. From `?V8::v8`:

> ```
> # Create a new context
> ctx <- v8();
>
> # Evaluate some code
> ctx$eval("var foo = 123")
> ctx$eval("var bar = 456")
> ctx$eval("foo+bar")
> ```

Ultimately it's going to get really frustrating for anything beyond little hacks, but it does work. You could likely source a whole script if you're clever, but I'm not sure it's worth it unless there's something that can absolutely only be done in JavaScript. Happy hacking!

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: If your trying this and are having trouble getting js_eval to work, the following worked for me: In the terminal
sudo gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3' -- --with-system-v8
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install v8-315

In R,
install.packages("V8”)
install_github("jeroenooms/js”)

Javascript will now work.
js::js_eval("(function() {return 'foo'})()")

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add this answer in case anyone was interested in using javascript/html in Jupyter R. The following is a very basic example:

```
test="<input type=\"file\" id=\"myFile\"/>"
as.factor(test)
```

The as.factor() removes the quotes but you can basically just assigned javascript/html to an r variable and call that variable. For example:

```
test="<input type=\"file\" id=\"myFile\"/>"
test
```

Comment: I want to run this code (which works in python jupyter notebook) in R:   

```%%javascript```
```var cell = Jupyter.notebook.get_selected_cell();```
```console.log(Jupyter.notebook.find_cell_index(cell));```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So I found another way to do this by  using the HTML function. Here is an example that will show and hide the code in a cell by clicking the text.

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML("""
 <style>
     // add your CSS styling here
 </style>
 <script>
     var code_show=true; //true -> hide code at first

     function code_toggle() {
         $('div.prompt').hide(); // always hide prompt

         if (code_show){
             $('div.input').hide();
         } else {
             $('div.input').show();
         }
         code_show = !code_show
     }
     $( document ).ready(code_toggle);
 </script>
 <a href="javascript:code_toggle()" 
     style="text-decoration:none; background-color: none;color:black;">
     <h1 align="center">Example</h1>
 </a>
""")
```