# Magic %% commands in R inside Jupyter

Tags: r, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

How do I run %%magic in R inside Jupyter?

```
%%javascript
IPython.OutputArea.auto_scroll_threshold = 99999;
```

The auto scroll feature on longer output is vastly annoying as I have several functions and scripts that spit out a lot of output.

The above Javascript works fine in python notebooks but not in R notebooks.

When I run the %% magic command in R, it barfs:

```
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:1:1: unexpected SPECIAL
1: %%
```

Any suggestions?

---

According to this post [disable_autoscroll.py](https://github.com/minrk/ipython_extensions/blob/master/extensions/disable_autoscroll.py), it may be possible to put that Javascript into a profile_dir/static/js/custom.js file.  Pray tell, where is the profile_dir on a Windows box?

I found: `c:/Anaconda2/Lib/site-packages/notebook/static/custom/custom.js` but that is the central custom.js file.

---

References:

[Auto-scrolling of long output should be configurable in the UI](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2172)

Comment: I'm shooting in the dark here, as I haven't used R inside Jupyter, but does `\\%\\%` or `\%\%` work? `%%` is an operator in R, so you would normally need escapes to get the text interpreted literally.

Comment: Or maybe [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34689500/496488) might help.

Comment: I still want to learn how to run magic commands. But I found that cell>all output>toggle scrolling does the trick!

Comment: The `%%magic` commands are an IPython kernel feature; they don't work in IRkernel. However, you can do `IRdisplay::display_javascript('some_js_code()')`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my anaconda install of the notebook, the `custom.js` file is in `%USERPROFILE%\.jupyter\custom\custom.js`.

For the "magics": magics are a thing of the python kernel, not the notebook. The R kernel does not implement a magic system and so these don't work. As mentioned [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291728/magic-commands-in-r-inside-jupyter#comment60249060_36291728), use `IRdisplay::display_javascript('IPython.OutputArea.auto_scroll_threshold = 99999;')` for your usecase.

Comment: I does not look like it is working -> Javascript Error: IPython is not defined